# Error when decoding certain Base64 strings, but not others

Tags: ios, swift, base64, arrays

To keep this simple, I'll only be encoding/decoding a single byte.

If I encode the byte 127, I get the base64 string "fw==" which can be successfully decoded back to byte 127. If, however, I encode a byte ≥ 128, then even though I can produce a base64 string without error (for example, byte 128 gives the string "gA=="), I get an error when I try to decode it.

Here's my code which can be copy-pasted into any Xcode playground to reproduce the problem:

```
func stringToByteArray(string: String) -> [UInt8] {
    var bytes: [UInt8] = [];
    for code in string.utf8 {
        bytes.append(UInt8(code));
    }
    return bytes;
}

func byteArrayToBase64(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    let nsdata: NSData = NSData(bytes: bytes as [Byte], length: bytes.count)
    let base64Encoded: NSString = nsdata.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0));
    return String(base64Encoded);
}

func base64ToByteArray(base64String: String) -> [UInt8] {
    let nsdata: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    let base64Decoded: NSString = NSString(data: nsdata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    return stringToByteArray(String(base64Decoded));
}

/* Replacing 127 with 128 below or greater produces an error */
var testString = byteArrayToBase64([127]);
base64ToByteArray(testString)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
let base64Decoded: NSString = NSString(data: nsdata, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

You convert the decoded data to a string. This fails for
`[128]` because that does not represent a valid UTF-8 sequence.

Here is a version that avoids the intermediate string:

```
func base64ToByteArray(base64String: String) -> [UInt8] {
    let nsdata: NSData = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))!
    // Create array of the required size ...
    var bytes = [UInt8](count: nsdata.length, repeatedValue: 0)
    // ... and fill it with the data
    nsdata.getBytes(&bytes)
    return bytes
}
```

*Remarks:*

- `options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0)` can be simplified
  to `options: nil`.
- There are some unnecessary type annotations and conversions in your code.
- Your function crashes if `baseString` is not a valid Base64 string.
  You could change it to return an optional.

Then it would look like this:

```
func byteArrayToBase64(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    let nsdata = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
    let base64Encoded = nsdata.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil);
    return base64Encoded;
}

func base64ToByteArray(base64String: String) -> [UInt8]? {
    if let nsdata = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: nil) {
        var bytes = [UInt8](count: nsdata.length, repeatedValue: 0)
        nsdata.getBytes(&bytes)
        return bytes
    }
    return nil // Invalid input
}
```

Example usage:

```
let testString = byteArrayToBase64([127, 128, 0, 130]);
println(testString) // Output: f4AAgg==
if let result = base64ToByteArray(testString) {
    println(result) // Output: [127, 128, 0, 130]
} else {
    println("failed")
}
```

---

Update for **Swift 2 / Xcode 7:**

```
func byteArrayToBase64(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    let nsdata = NSData(bytes: bytes, length: bytes.count)
    let base64Encoded = nsdata.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]);
    return base64Encoded;
}

func base64ToByteArray(base64String: String) -> [UInt8]? {
    if let nsdata = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64String, options: []) {
        var bytes = [UInt8](count: nsdata.length, repeatedValue: 0)
        nsdata.getBytes(&bytes, length: bytes.count)
        return bytes
    }
    return nil // Invalid input
}

let testString = byteArrayToBase64([127, 128, 0, 130]);
print(testString) // Output: f4AAgg==
if let result = base64ToByteArray(testString) {
    print(result) // Output: [127, 128, 0, 130]
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```

---

Update for **Swift 3** and later:

```
func byteArrayToBase64(bytes: [UInt8]) -> String {
    let data = Data(bytes)
    let base64Encoded = data.base64EncodedString()
    return base64Encoded;
}

func base64ToByteArray(base64String: String) -> [UInt8]? {
    guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)  else {
        return nil
    }
    return Array(data)
}

let testString = byteArrayToBase64(bytes: [127, 128, 0, 130]);
print(testString) // Output: f4AAgg==
if let result = base64ToByteArray(base64String: testString) {
    print(result) // Output: [127, 128, 0, 130]
} else {
    print("failed")
}
```